# NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method removeOnPageChangeListener

Tags: android

I am using [ongakuer/CircleIndicator](https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator) library to add viewpager indicators. I have used the sample code as it is except changing a small [code](https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/me/relex/circleindicatorsample/ViewpagerActivity.java#L28) from `customViewpager.addOnPageChangeListener`to `customViewpager.setOnPageChangeListener`because it was showing compile error. After that there was no compile error.

When I run the activity, I straightaway get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method removeOnPageChangeListener(Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewPager$OnPageChangeListener;)V in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewPager; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager' appears in /data/app/com.app.app-2/base.apk)
            at me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator.setViewPager(CircleIndicator.java:127)
            at com.app.app.ViewpagerActivity.onCreate(ViewpagerActivity.java:24)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I had later on decided to drop the idea of using this lib. I will let you know if I use it.

Answer (score 9):

Faced a similar issue with [RecyclerView.Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) -

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setAdapterCount ...
```

Invalidating caches and then restarting Android Studio resolved the error in my case. [You can find directions to invalidate caches in IntelliJ (the software Android Studio is built upon) at this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/cleaning-system-cache.html).

Comment: any solution..?

Comment: As mentioned - "Invalidating caches and then restarting Android Studio" worked for me

Comment: This post could be improved with links to directions on how to find and invalidate the Android Studio caches! Update: Edited.

Comment: Invalidating and restarting WITH a clean and rebuild is what fixed it for me.

Comment: Sad to know as it isn't working now

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and in my case the solution was as follows:

#### Solution:

- Go to the **SDK Manager**.
- Go to the **SDK Tools** tab.
- Make sure you install the latest version of **Android Support Library, rev 22**.
- Now try running your app again.

#### Explanation:

- **removeOnPageChangeListener** was only added in Revision 22 of the support-v4 library.
- For some reason, Android Studio will not let you know that you don't have the full revision downloaded and installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I used a version of **support-v4** library which wasn't compatible with my other support libraries:

```
compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1') {
    // Force stable version of support-v4
    force = true
}
```

Unfortunately, the only solution I found is by removing **support-v4** library from my build altogether.