# My application crashes when listview is loaded in fragment layout

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, custom-adapter

I am trying to show a listview in a fragment layout; for that i have used custom adapter.Note that on a button click, fragment is changed. But on that button click application crashes, I don't know what is actual problem please help.

This is my Fragment Class:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {    
    public void Fragment1()
    {        
    }        

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        return rootView;
    }

    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        int img_arr[] = {R.drawable.emmastone,
                R.drawable.chloegracemoretz,
                R.drawable.salmankhan,
                R.drawable.emilia,
                R.drawable.kitharington,
                R.drawable.scarlettjohansson,
                R.drawable.sophie,
                R.drawable.deepika,
                R.drawable.leonardodicaprio};
        String name_arr[] = {"Emma", "Chloe", "Salman", "Emilia", "Kit", "Scarlet", "Sophie", "Deepika", "Leonardo" };
        String msg_arr[] = {"Free at 8pm?", "I miss you <3", "Mota ho raha hun kia karon?", "Not in mood", "Danny or yagrit?", "Where are you?", "got engaged <3", "Give my money", "50 is enough" };

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return img_arr.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.chats,null);
            ImageView img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_name);
            TextView msg = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_msg);

            img.setImageResource(img_arr[position]);
            name.setText(name_arr[position]);
            msg.setText(msg_arr[position]);

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

This is in logcat:

```
0-21 23:52:21.581 3040-3040/com.example.farhan.a13_f_8310_lab_10_oct_fragments E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.farhan.a13_f_8310_lab_10_oct_fragments, PID: 3040

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getLayoutInflater()Landroid/view/LayoutInflater; in class
Lcom/example/farhan/a13_f_8310_lab_10_oct_fragments/Fragment1; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.example.farhan.a13_f_8310_lab_10_oct_fragments.Fragment1' appears in /data/app/com.example.farhan.a13_f_8310_lab_10_oct_fragments-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk)
                                                                                                      at com.example.farhan.a13_f_8310_lab_10_oct_fragments.Fragment1$CustomAdapter.getView(Fragment1.java:91)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method removeOnPageChangeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953820/nosuchmethoderror-no-virtual-method-removeonpagechangelistener)

Comment: @GernotKrost the link  you have given is not solving my problem

Comment: can you please paste your `fragment_fragment1.xml` here ?