# Can not remove item from RecyclerView (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError notifyItemRemoved(I))

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When i want to removing item i got this error :

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method notifyItemRemoved(I)V in class Lir/adapters/GridRecycleAdapter; or its super classes (declaration of 'ir.adapters.GridRecycleAdapter' appears in /data/app/ir.selfinsta-1/split_lib_directories_apk.apk)

Code :

```
public class GridRecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private final String TAG = "GridRecycleAdapter";
private ArrayList<Item> items;

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //some code
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder h, int position) {
    //some code
}


@Override
public void onViewRecycled(RecyclerView.ViewHolder h) {
    //some code
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return items.size() ;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

/*
 * for remove item
 */
private void removeItem(int position){
    //remove item
    items.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position,items.size());
}
}
```

build.gradle :

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

build.gradle depency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
```

Comment: Seems weird . Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953820/nosuchmethoderror-no-virtual-method-removeonpagechangelistener. Also let us know if you are using Proguard ?

Comment: I checked this page before but problem not solved. yes this project using proguard

Comment: Try after disable proguard in debug mode if it works the you have to add rules for support library.

Comment: Yeah ! . The problem solved . just for proguard . can yo share true proguard for support libraries ?

Comment: Use rules from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24935165/4168607 . Good luck .

Comment: Thanks again :))))