# JobScheduler Android Pie updated methods not working

Tags: android

I am trying to sync background data to server using JobScheduler. According to latest update of pie it should be done using new methods recommended. But it says the virtual methods are not found

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0 I tried using these methods but my code does not run.

```
ComponentName componentInfo = new ComponentName(this, SyncService.class);

    JobInfo.Builder jobInfoBuilder = new JobInfo.Builder(1, componentInfo)
            .setEstimatedNetworkBytes(100000, 100000)
            .setPrefetch(true)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(true)
            .setPeriodic(13 * 1000 * 60);
    JobInfo info = jobInfoBuilder.build();
   JobScheduler scheduler =(JobScheduler)getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    scheduler.schedule(info);
```

Error as below:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setEstimatedNetworkBytes(JJ)Landroid/app/job/JobInfo$Builder; in class Landroid/app/job/JobInfo$Builder; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.app.job.JobInfo$Builder' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
        at com.avalanche.avalanchetracker.MainActivity.scheduleJob(MainActivity.java:35)
        at com.avalanche.avalanchetracker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Maybe try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953820/nosuchmethoderror-no-virtual-method-removeonpagechangelistener)

Comment: tried this one but still same problem.